# AWS Athena cost for requests from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-athena

If I have 1000000 items in S3 and I want to query all these items by Athena, will I be charged for 1000000 GET Item S3 operations (and of course cost of amount of scanned data)?

Or will Athena treat ONE select as ONE get from S3?

Documentation says:

`Amazon Athena queries data directly from Amazon S3. There are no additional storage charges for querying your data with Athena. You are charged standard S3 rates for storage, requests, and data transfer.`

Thank you in advance for answer!

Answer (score 1):

You will pay for every GetRequest Athena has to make to fulfill your query. If your query has to read all files to calculate the average of a column, you will be charged for 1000000 GetRequests.